# Finding the group generated by 2 given 3 * 3 binary matrices

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Having trouble completing this exercise. I posted a few questions on subgroups generated by subsets of a group. But am still at odds on how to solve a problem of this type.

The orders of the first and second matrices are 3 and 2 respectively. Furthermore If we denote them by A and B respectively then (BA)<sup>2</sup> = I.

I also tried the set, { A , A<sup>2</sup>, B , BA , BA<sup>2</sup>, I } where I is the 3*3 identity matrix.

> Find the smallest group under matrix multiplication that contains the matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$Write down its elements. Is this group abelian? Justify your answer.

Comment: Hint for visualization purposes: consider the action of these matrices on the vector $v=(1, 2, 3)$...

Comment: So you are saying these matrices correspond to (1 2 3) and (1 2) in S3.

Comment: Ishfaaq: precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $A^3 = I, B^2 = I$, so clearly
$$
\{I, A, A^2, B, AB, A^2B\}
$$
are all distinct elements. Now $(BA)^2 = I$, so
$$
BA = (BA)^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1} = A^2B
$$
Now any word of the form
$$
A^{i_1}B^{i_2}A^{i_3}B^{i_4}\ldots A^{i_n}B^{i_{n+1}}
$$
can be reduced to one of the form $A^iB^j$ (by induction, if you will). For instance,
$$
ABA^2 = ABAA = AA^2BA = A^2B
$$

So the above set enumerates all the elements of $G$. Also $AB \neq BA$, so the group is non-abelian.

Comment: once you have shown $BA = A^2B =A(AB)$ you can say that $AB=BA$ implies $id= A$

Comment: Thanks people. Much appreciated.